# Command Prompt / List files within specified sub folders

Tags: directory, command, subdirectory, prompt

I have a Directory with 100 sub folders. Call them Top 1, Top 2, Top 3. Within each of those I have 3 dozen sub folders. Call them Sub 1, Sub 2, Sub 3, etc.

I need to find all files within Sub 2, for each Top folder. The top folder name varies. But each Top folder has the same exact Sub folder structure.
All of the files within the Sub 2 can be listed regardless of their file extension.

\Top 1\Sub 2

\Top 2\Sub 2

\Top 3\Sub 2

etc.

Is there a Command Prompt that can help list this?

Cheers,

Answer (score 0):

If os is windows

`tree` command if I remember it right.

Will do

Comment: "tree I:\" Lists more than the sub folders.

Comment: Yes it will print everything under the folder. But if you need to print files from  specific folder then I think  you need a script to do that.